# Twilio - best way to learn of a client disconnect to set task router worker to unavailable

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-taskrouter

Does anyone know a way to learn about a Twilio Voice Client register/unregister?  There doesn't seem to be any webhooks associated with this.  I would like to know when they disconnect so I can make sure to update their task router worked to unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your post that you are using Twilio Javascript SDK and making calls using the browser. If this is correct, then you can listen for the [destroy or unregister events](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliodevice#unregistered-event):

```
const device = new Device(token);

device.on('unregistered', () => 
    // Do something to update TaskWorker status
});
```

However, this will be fragile if the end-user loses Internet connectivity, quits the browser/closes the tab, or just powers off the computer. A more reliable method would be to the put the "ready" user into a [Conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/conference) while they wait for calls. If the user hangs-up the conference will send a "participant-leave" webhook event that your Server can then use to update the Taskrouter worker status to unavailable.